# How to load Spring resource bundle from tomcat conf directory

Tags: spring, tomcat, resourcebundle

I am trying to load the properties files located in the tomcat conf folder but the code below ends up causing a Missing Resource exception.If I use a property placeholder I can load properties files from tomcat conf fine.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
            <value>file:${catalina.base}/conf/messages</value>

    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to externalize your resources and use ResourceBundle this is how I did it using ClassLoader.

```
private static ClassLoader loader;

private static void setUp()
{
    String path = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
    File file = new File(path +"/conf/error_messages");
    URL[] urls = new URL[0];
    try {
        urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
}
```

Now when I need to load the correct messages: ex: errors_en.properties located outside the application.

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("errors", requestLocale, loader);
```